# Crypto algorithm '' not supported in this context

Tags: c#, wcf, sharepoint, web-config, service-application

I have a SharePoint 2010 service application and when I try to execute some code on the channel I receive the error:

> Crypto algorithm '' not supported in this context.System.NotSupportedException: Crypto algorithm '' not supported in this context.

There really is just two '' quotes, nothing in between them. I am using IssuedToken for my authenticationMode. Here is my web.config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <compilation debug="true" defaultLanguage="C#" />
    </system.web>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <behaviors>
            <serviceBehaviors>
                <behavior name="TLAPITypeBehaviors" >
                    <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
                </behavior>
            </serviceBehaviors>
        </behaviors>
        <services>
            <service name="AF.TipAndLeadAPI.TipAndLeadAPIServiceApplication" behaviorConfiguration="TLAPITypeBehaviors">
                <endpoint binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="TLAPIServiceHttpBinding"
                          contract="AF.TipAndLeadAPI.ITipAndLeadAPIContract"
                          address="" />
            </service>
        </services>
        <bindings>
            <customBinding>
                <binding name="TLAPIServiceHttpBinding">
                    <security authenticationMode="IssuedTokenOverTransport" allowInsecureTransport="true" />
                    <textMessageEncoding>
                        <readerQuotas maxStringContentLength="2048576000" maxArrayLength="2097152000" />
                    </textMessageEncoding>
                    <httpTransport maxReceivedMessageSize="2162688" authenticationScheme="Anonymous" useDefaultWebProxy="false" />
                </binding>
            </customBinding>
        </bindings>
    </system.serviceModel>
    <system.webServer>
        <security>
            <authentication>
                <anonymousAuthentication enabled="true" />
                <windowsAuthentication enabled="false" />
            </authentication>
        </security>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

And my client.config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <client>
            <endpoint  address=""
                name="http"
                      binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="TLAPIServiceHttpBinding"
                      contract="AF.TipAndLeadAPI.ITipAndLeadAPIContract" />
        </client>
        <bindings>
            <customBinding>
                <binding name="TLAPIServiceHttpBinding">

                    <security authenticationMode="IssuedTokenOverTransport" allowInsecureTransport="true" />
                    <textMessageEncoding>
                        <readerQuotas maxStringContentLength="204857600" maxArrayLength="209715200" />
                    </textMessageEncoding>
                    <httpTransport maxReceivedMessageSize="216268800" authenticationScheme="Anonymous" useDefaultWebProxy="false" />
                </binding>
            </customBinding>
        </bindings>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

When I change my authenticationMode to something like IssuedTokenOverTransport I get an assembly mismatch error. When I change it to anything with certificates, I get a certificate error, so my guess is, it has to do with the authenticationMode.

Any help would be much appreciated.